# Why I need to set the margin of a div to a negative value when its siblings take positive value to position themselves to the top?

Tags: html, css

I set the margin of div#hdesign to margin:0px 250px to put it to the top..To set div#hTestimonial to the Top, it takes negative values like margin:-200px 300px;
Why is this the case when both are sibllings of the same parent?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Slicing</title>

<style type="text/css">
html,body{  
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;

    }
div#wrapper{    
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        line-height:normal;
        border:#000 thin dotted;
        background-color:#FF3;
        font-size:10px;

    }

div#wrapper div#header{
        width:100%;
        height:30%;
        border:#000 thin dotted;

    }


div#wrapper div#body{
        width:100%;
        height:50%;
        border:#000 thin dotted;
        background-color:#096;
    }

div#wrapper div#footer{
        width:100%;
        height:20.0%;
        border:#000 thin dotted;

    }



div#wrapper div#header div#hlogo{
        width:25%;
        height:95%;

        margin:0px ;

        background-color:#096;


    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hdesign{
        width:180px;
        height:90px;
        border:#000 thin dotted;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:115px;
        margin:0px 250px;
        background-color:#3C9;
        opacity:0.5;
        line-height:0px;
    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hTestimonial{
        //width:40%;
        margin:0px 300px;
        width:150px;
        height:100%;
        border:#000 thin dotted;


    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hlogo div#Logoheader{
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:bold;
        background-color:#F6F;
        text-align:center;
        height:30px;
        width:70%;
        margin:0px 0px 0px 51px;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:#000 thin dotted;



    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hlogo div#Logodesc{
        font-size:10px;
        height:30px;
        background-color:#F90;
        width:70%;
        margin:0px 0px 5px 51px;
        overflow:hidden;
        line-height:0.5;
        text-align:center;
        border:#000 thin dotted;
    }


div#wrapper div#header div#hdesign div{


        padding:60px 65px 0px 0px;

    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hdesign div p{
        color:#000;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

div#wrapper div#header div#hTestimonial{
        ;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="hlogo">


                    <div id="Logoheader">RamblingSoul</div>
                    <div id="Logodesc">
                        <p>A Free CSS Template From</p>
                        <p>RamblingSoul</p>
                    </div>


        </div>
        <div id="hdesign">
                <div><p>Great Design </p><p>Guaranteed</p></div>

        </div>
        <div id="hTestimonial">
                <div > <h3>Client Testimonial</h3>
                        <p>ahkshdskka jkljsald</p>
                        <p>ahkshdskka jkljsald</p>
                        <p>ahkshdskka jkljsald</p>
                        <p>ahkshdskka<a href=""> Read More</a></p>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is incomplete, what is the parent? what is the previous sibling before #hdesign?

Comment: Corrected the styling, so it's understandable... wait for it to be approved.

Comment: @Niklas: http://jsbin.com/ayuxi5

Comment: The reason hdesign is at the top, even with 0 top margin is because it has been set with `position:absolute` to `top:0`. If you do the same with the hTestimonial div, you should get similar results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Element `#hdesign` gets aligned to the top because of `{position: absolute; top: 0;}`. It doesn't really need the `margin-top: 0` (given in shorthand).

Element `#hTestimonial` on the other hand is a statically positioned element, and so in the normal rendering flow. Thus any content rendered before it (that's not positioned `fixed` or `absolute`) affects its positioning.

[This tutorial](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) should further clarify the differences in positioning.